# No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3 available for offline mode

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I installed JetBrains IDEA 15.0.2 with android support on my computer that is disconnected from Internet.
After that the project sync give an error that gradle is not existed, so I solve the problem by downloading gradle 2.2.1 and extracting it in its corresponding position
But after that a new sync error occurs that say "No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3 available for offline mode"
How can I solve error, at the same time keeping my conputer disconnected from Internet

Answer (score 20):

Try the following steps:

1. Un-check "Offline work" in File>Settings>Gradle>Global Gradle Settings
2. Re-sync the project, for example by restarting the Android Studio
3. Once synced, you can check the option again to work offline.

Answer (score 5):

I faced similar kind of issue in android studio because its also uses the gradle so my problem was app's source code was written in old version of gradle but i have the latest android studio with latest gradle. so changed the classpath dependency to have latest gradle version

**Update the Classpath under dependency in build.gradle file at project level**
from

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

**to**

```
dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Comment: Don't you have IntelliJ Idea? I think he's asking for it.