# Gradle not downloading dependencies in intelliJ idea

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, dependencies, log4j

I am building a Java project in Intellij Idea IDE.
Following is my build.gradle file:

```
group 'fyp_group09'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
}
```

I use a proxy connection provided by school and have done the required proxy setup in the IDE.
The log4j dependencies are not getting downloaded. I've refreshed the gradle project many times, but it does not download the dependencies and does not even give any error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does it by chance give you a message? There's a notification icon near the bottom right-hand corner of the window. It maybe green, yellow, or red.

Comment: Yes now I saw and got the following message: `Warning:<i><b>root project 'isothetic_cover': Unable to resolve additional project configuration.</b>
Details: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactResolveException: Could not download log4j.jar (log4j:log4j:1.2.17): No cached version available for offline mode</i>
`

Comment: I'm not familiar with that issue but maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308889/no-cached-version-of-com-android-tools-buildgradle1-2-3-available-for-offline) will help you.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following trick as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34309901/4022132), worked well for me:

> Un-check "Offline work" in File>Settings>Gradle>Global Gradle Settings

Comment: Thank You.You **saved** me a lot

Comment: Don't have a clue how I got mine got checked but this solved all my issues I've been having

Answer (score 12):

We had this, worked after doing File>Invalidate Caches / Restart...